# Stripboard with 2.0mm spacing

Tags: pcb

I have a rotary switch with 20 x 2 pins in a rectangular form, and I need to connect almost all pins, so I thought to buy a PCB board for that.

The problem is that the spacing between the pins is about 2.0mm which PCB boards I can't find on the internet...

Is there another way to connect all those pins?
I could, of course, make my own PCB board, but I don't have a that good drilling machine for those small holes.

What would you suggest? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.0mm proto boards exist, but they are rare and EXPENSIVE. They're also oversized if you only have one 2.00mm pitch component. Vectorboard makes them (all their stuff is overpriced) and Digikey and Mouser carry their products.

A better solution is Proto-Advantage's so-called "pitch changer" PCBs. They have their own online store, but Digikey also carries their products:

http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/index.php?cPath=3800_3803

EDIT: Seems Proto-Advantage only carries single row pitch changers and if you have two rows that are 2.00mm apart, then you probably don't have enough space to use two back-to-back pitch changers.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A search for [2mm prototype board](https://www.google.com/search?q=2mm+prototype+board&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3rb_-9c3gAhVcUxUIHc7bAyQQ_AUIDigB&biw=1050&bih=1520) will give you a good start.

A couple of points:

- We don't usually call those "printed circuit boards" but prototyping boards or, in Europe at least, Veroboard after Vero, one of the earliest manufacturers.
- The standard boards are 0.1" = 2.54 mm spacing.